# console.log(action) does not display in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, console.log, reducers

I have multiple reducers and this reducer never appear for any `console.log()` but for `default` case it always goes to another `xxx_fetch_success` payload.

Here is my  **actions/index.js**

```
export * from './ItemActions';
```

Here is my **actions/types.js**

```
export const ITEM_UPDATE = 'item_update';
export const ITEM_CREATE = 'item_create';
export const ITEMS_FETCH_SUCCESS = 'items_fetch_success';
```

Here is my **actions/ItemActions.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { ITEM_UPDATE, ITEM_CREATE, ITEMS_FETCH_SUCCESS } from './types';

export const itemUpdate =  ({ prop, value }) => {
    return {
        type: ITEM_UPDATE,
        payload: { prop, value }
    };
};

export const itemsFetch = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref(`items/`)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                dispatch({ type: ITEMS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
            });
    };
};
```

Here is my **reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import ItemFormReducer from './ItemFormReducer';
import ItemReducer from './ItemReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    itemForm: ItemFormReducer,
    items: ItemReducer,
});
```

Here is my **reducers/ItemReducer.js**

```
import { ITEMS_FETCH_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case ITEMS_FETCH_SUCCESS:
            console.log("ITEM_FETCH_SUCCESS: ",action);
            return state;
        default:
            console.log("FROM DEFAULT: ",action);
            return state;
    }
};
```

Here is my **reducers/ItemFormReducer.js**

```
import {
    ITEM_UPDATE,
    ITEM_CREATE,
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    photo: '',
    item: '',
    category: '',
    price: '',
    description: '',
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case ITEM_UPDATE: 
            return { ...state, [ action.payload.prop ]: action.payload.value };
        case ITEM_CREATE:
            return INITIAL_STATE;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here is my **screens/Menu.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { itemsFetch } from '../../actions';
class Menu extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.itemsFetch();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Menu</Text>
                <Text>Menu</Text>
                <Text>Menu</Text>
                <Text>Menu</Text>
                <Text>Menu</Text>
                <Text>Menu</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, { itemsFetch })(Menu);
```

Here is my **Firebase rules:**

```
{

  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */

  "rules": {

     "items" : {

      "$itemId":{

        ".read": true,

        ".write":"auth.uid === data.child('ownerId').val() || data.child('ownerId').val() === null"

      }

    },

    "users":{

      "$uid":{

        ".read": true,

        ".write":"$uid === auth.uid"

      }

    },

  }

}
```

Here is my **Firebase Realtime Database structure:**

```
ProjectName

      - items

      - users
```

Problem is console.log(action) in the **reducers/ItemReducer.js** never appear but the `console.log(action)` in `default` case is appear with another object data payload
Can you please help me out, thank you before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with React Native or Action in redux. It is because of rule in the firebase security that I block all write operation.